# Qual a finalidade do stdClass no PHP?

Tags: php, stdclass

- Qual é a finalidade da classe pré-definida **stdClass** no PHP?
- Detalhadamente o que ele faz?
- Qual a sua importância?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A StdClass é uma classe predefinida do PHP. Ela é vazia, ou seja, não possui métodos nem propriedades. Mas qual o objetivo disto? Ela é a classe padrão dos objetos que não são declarados, ou seja, quando você converte um array ou algum outro tipo para objeto, na verdade está criando um objeto da StdClass. É útil também utilizar a StdClass quando se deseja criar um objeto vazio e ir adicionando as propriedades conforme necessário.

Um exemplo de uso da StdClass:

```
$obj = new StdClass;

$obj->nome = 'teste';

var_dump($obj);
```

[Fonte](http://angelitomg.com/blog/o-que-e-a-stdclass-do-php/)

Comment: Da pra criar direto? tipo como um array? Exemplo: `$arr = array('nome' => 'teste', ...)` assim: `$obj = new stdClass('nome' => 'teste')`

Comment: Vc precisa instanciar ele antes de passar o valor.

Comment: standardClass...

Comment: @José, fazendo um typecast, exemplo: `$o = (object)array('foo' => 'bar');` Poderá então acessar dessa forma `$o->foo` ou mesmo criar novas propriedades `$o->outro = 'valor';`

Answer (score -5):

A stdClass é útil quando você precisa criar objetos temporários ou simples sem definir uma classe formal. Isso é especialmente útil em situações em que você precisa de um objeto para armazenar dados temporários ou passar dados entre funções.

Exemplo de criação de um objeto php stdClass:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->nome = 'João';
$obj->idade = 25;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Marcos, sua resposta atualmente está dizendo basicamente a mesma coisa que a outra que existe desde 2016. Se a ideia era acrescentar algo, não ficou claro. Poderia editar a resposta e tentar detalhar melhor?