# Acessando informações de um Objeto

Tags: php, array

Como eu faria para acessar `Type` e `cm` com esse array?

```
object(stdClass)#38 (3) {
  ["op"]=>
  string(1) "&"
  ["c"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#32 (3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(10) "completion"
      ["cm"]=>
      int(1227)
      ["e"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  ["showc"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os dados forem repetídos, você pode usar um loop para acessá-los.

```
foreach ($object->c as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->type;
        echo $value->cm;
}
```

Se for acessar diretamente, seria assim:

```
echo $object->c[0]->type; // minúsculo, e não maiúsculo
echo $object->c[0]->cm;
```

**Nota**: Você perguntou sobre "acessar um `array`", mas isso é um objeto (o `stdClass`, que é o objeto padrão do PHP).

Relacionado:

[Qual a finalidade do stdClass no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132319/qual-a-finalidade-do-stdclass-no-php)