# Criando mensagem de sucesso ao conseguir realizar uma ação LARAVEL 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, front-end, layout

Estou tentando fazer com que seja informado uma mensagem de sucesso em uma **`div`**  ao ser realizado uma ação, porem não consegui ainda, o erro que aparece é:

> (3/3) ErrorException Undefined variable: sucess (View:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetoslaravel/clinica-beta/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetoslaravel/clinica-beta/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

meu código está da seguinte forma 
**no layout da pagina**

```
@if(isset($errors) and count($errors) > 0)
     <div id="msg" class="alert alert-error">                
                <p>{{$error}}</p>
     </div>           
@elseif(isset($sucess) and count($sucess) > 0)
     <div id="msg" class="alert alert-sucess">                
                <p>{{$sucess}}</p>
     </div>
@endif
```

**na controller esta da seguinte forma**

```
public function ativar($id) 
{
    $apt = $this->ModelApartamento->find($id);
    $liberacao = $apt->verificarAtivar();
    if ($liberacao) {
        $dados = ['status' => 'L'];
        //dd($dados);
        $update = $apt->update($dados);
        if ($update) {
            return redirect()
                   ->back()
                   ->with('sucess','Apartamento ativado com sucesso'); 
        } else {
            return redirect()
                   ->back()
                   ->with('errors', 'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar ativar apartamento');
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()
                   ->back()
                   ->with('errors', 'Apartamento está com paciente no momento');
    }
}
```

Comment: A variavel não foi definida, ela é definida no controller se houver sucesso do update, então o correto no seu templete é fazer "se for error mostre senão mostre o sucesso" e você esta perguntando para erro e sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe várias formas de fazer um `status`, ao meu ver o seu é errado, inclusive porque o seu teste no `if` não testa corretamente as variáveis e poderia ser feito ***por exemplo da seguinte forma***:

[Crie uma variável de um classe predefinida no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132319/qual-a-finalidade-do-stdclass-no-php), ou seja, stdClass, e no código do `controller` ***faça essas alterações***:

```
public function ativar($id) 
{
    $apt = $this->ModelApartamento->find($id);
    $liberacao = $apt->verificarAtivar();

    $st = new StdClass;

    if ($liberacao) 
    {
        $dados = ['status' => 'L'];        
        $update = $apt->update($dados);
        if ($update) 
        {
            $st->status = true;
            $st->message = "Apartamento ativado com sucesso";
            return redirect()
                   ->back()
                   ->with('st', $st); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            $st->status = false;
            $st->message = "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar ativar apartamento";
            return redirect()
                   ->back()
                   ->with('st', $st);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $st->status = false;
        $st->message = "Apartamento está com paciente no momento";
        return redirect()
                   ->back()
                   ->with('st', $st);
    }
}
```

e na `View` também ***faça essas alterações***:

```
@if(session()->has('st'))
@if(!session()->get('st')->status)
    <div id="msg" class="alert alert-error">                
        <p>{{$st->message}}</p>
    </div>           
@else
    <div id="msg" class="alert alert-sucess">                
        <p>{{$st->message}}</p>
    </div>
@endif
@endif
```

poderia ainda ficar melhor na sua `View` da seguinte forma:

```
@if(session()->has('st'))
<div 
  id="msg" 
  class="@if(session()->get('st')->status){{'alert alert-sucess'}}@else{{'alert alert-error'}}@endif">
    <p>{{$st->message}}</p>
</div>
@endif
```

essa seria uma das formas.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Qual a finalidade do stdClass no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132319/qual-a-finalidade-do-stdclass-no-php)
- [Predefined Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)
- [PHP stdClass: Storing Data in an Object Instead of an Array](https://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/)
- [HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues não neh! se for true ele inverte e cai no else que no caso da resposta é sucesso? correto?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo pegar o valor dessa variavel na view , no caso ela esta redirecionando para a index.blade.php , tem alguma outra forma em que eu não precise ficar sempre criando uma instancia de StdClass? no caso estou pensando nisso para um sistema maior com muitos cruds e muitas mensagens de sucesso ou error

Comment: @MárcioCésar não precisa mudar essa forma, talvez o contexto seu é maior e isso que atrapalha, por exemplo como você utiliza o código e porque está usando back()?

Comment: esta ação ativar esta sendo mostrada na index , utilizo o back() para voltar a index()  porem quando envio o with('st',$st) no template.blade.php ele diz que a variavel não esta definida  o template esta sendo chamado no arquivo index tbm.

Comment: tente assim eu edite @MárcioCésar (`withInput`) dá uma olhada na resposta

Comment: @MárcioCésar qual é o nome da rota da pagina `index.blade.php`?

Comment: rota é 'apartamentos.index'

Comment: Na verdade ali é uma sessão eu até eu me confundi dá uma olhada na edição @MárcioCésar

Comment: consegui aqui irmão , muito obrigado, estou pensando em uma solução para não precisar ficar declarando sempre a variavel $st e nem instanciando ela . tem dicas ?

Comment: Uma vez eu fiz uma classe que dependendo do evento era caracterizado por mensagens padrões ... seria uma instância da classe mas, eu usava de uma forma que não precisa ficar instânciando o próprio laravel pelo service provider fazia isso... @MárcioCésar