# Não consigo acessar o valor da array que recebo de uma API

Tags: php

Boa tarde, estou caminhando aos poucos no php, mas essa parte de array ainda fico bem confuso, pesquisei bastante na internet e dei umas lida no manual do php mas não conseguir fazer o que eu quero, eu estou fazendo uns testes com wordpress, nele estou usando uma api que me retorna um array com vários resultados, queria armazenar uma específica parte dessa array, segue a array quando dou print_t

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 10978 
[code] => al060819#3 
[amount] => 90.00 
[date_created] => 2019-08-05T13:35:28 
[date_created_gmt] => 2019-08-05T18:35:28 
[date_modified] => 2019-08-05T18:52:58 
[date_modified_gmt] => 2019-08-05T23:52:58 
[discount_type] => percent 
[description] => 
[date_expires] => 2019-08-07T00:00:00 
[date_expires_gmt] => 2019-08-07T05:00:00 
[usage_count] => 15 
[individual_use] => 
[product_ids] => Array ( ) 
[excluded_product_ids] => Array ( ) 
[usage_limit] => 
[usage_limit_per_user] => 
[limit_usage_to_x_items] => 
[free_shipping] => 
[product_categories] => Array ( ) 
[excluded_product_categories] => Array ( ) 
[exclude_sale_items] => 
[minimum_amount] => 0.00 
[maximum_amount] => 0.00 
[email_restrictions] => Array ( ) 
[used_by] => Array ( 
[0] => 88 
[1] => 90 
[2] => 92 
[3] => 89 
[4] => 99 
[5] => 101 
[6] => 100 
[7] => 102 
[8] => 106 
[9] => 108 
[10] => 116 
[11] => 117 
[12] => 116 
[13] => 123 
[14] => 122 ) 
[meta_data] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 25606 
[key] => count_items 
[value] => 0 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 25619 
[key] => slide_template 
[value] => default ) ) 
[_links] => stdClass Object ( 
[self] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[href] => Null) ) 
[collection] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[href] => Null ) ) ) ) )
```

queria acessar o used_by e salvar em outra variavel, tentei de algumas formas, mas todas retornava erro ex:

```
$teste = $array[0]['used_by'];
```

ou

```
$teste = $array['used_by'];
```

msg de error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php on line 37
```

alguém poderia me explicar como funciona? pois estou muito perdido nisso, desculpa pela pergunta besta, acho que pode ser repetida, mas pesquisei bastante antes e não consegui entender, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Se os dados forem JSON, o link acima responderá a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem de erro diz que você não pode utilizar um objeto do tipo `stdClass` como um *array*.

Se olhar sua saída, verá que a posição 0 do seu *array* é um objeto `stdClass`, não outro *array*:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 10978 
    [code] => al060819#3 
    [amount] => 90.00 
    ...
```

Então está errado fazer `$array[0]['used_by']`.

- [Qual a finalidade do stdClass no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132319/5878)
- [PHP Classes Predefinidas](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php)

Para acessar um valor de um objeto precisa ser com `->`:

```
$array[0]->used_by
```

Comment: hmm, não sabia dessa rs, vou dar uma lida nos artigos que o senhor mandou, muito obrigado

Comment: Sei que aqui não é o local ideal e que talvez você nem veja, mas é possível usar esse valor da array em um select? tipo 
$teste = $array[0]->used_by
SELECT * FROM teste WHERE user = $teste
seria possível usar essa array no where? ou só fazendo um loop mesmo?

Comment: @Faillen Eu vejo todos os comentários que recebo... e sim, deveria ser possível. Você pode fazer a interpolação: `"SELECT ... FROM teste WHERE coluna = {$array[0]->used_by}"` ou algo do gênero

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente, vou fazer os testes aqui. Obrigado mesmo